# Spotfire SaveAs using ironPython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to SaveAs a document as a library item on 'onPropertyChange' event using ironpython script.
the script`s code attached to the property :

```
# Import namespaces
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Library import *

# Set the folder path and file name
folderName = "/Spotfire Test Folder/Reports"
fileName = "Test File"

# Set up the LibraryMangager and ensure that we can 
# access the folder path specified
libraryManager = Document.GetService(LibraryManager)
success, libraryFolder = libraryManager.TryGetItem(folderName, LibraryItemType.Folder)

# Embed the data
Document.Data.SaveSettings.EmbedAllSourceData = 1

# Save the document back to the Library
Application.SaveAs(libraryFolder, fileName, LibraryItemMetadataSettings(), DocumentSaveSettings())
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error :

**Invalid operation 'BeginAggregatedTransaction' to the command history when in state 'Executing'**

- Is there a problem with the script ? in case not , is there a way to save as a library item using a script or an api function (via javascript or ironpython)?

Comment: Is the behavior the same i webplayer as in fat client ?

Comment: yes, it throws the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all ironpython scripts in spotfire run in transactions, and some api functions, such as 'SaveAs' are trying to invoke a second transaction, which causes the script to fail.

therefore, the 'SaveAs' function call should run on the application thread, and thereby get outside the transaction.

the final code which works :

```
# Import namespaces
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import ApplicationThread
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Library import *

# Declaring the function which will run async
def g(app, folder, fileName, metaData, saveSettings):
   def f():
      app.SaveAs(folder, fileName, metaData, saveSettings)
   return f

# Set the folder path and file name
folderName = "/Spotfire Test Folder/Reports"
fileName = "Test File"

# Set up the LibraryMangager and ensure that we can 
# access the folder path specified
libraryManager = Document.GetService(LibraryManager)
success, libraryFolder = libraryManager.TryGetItem(folderName, LibraryItemType.Folder)

# Executing the function on the application thread, and Save the document back to the Library
Application.GetService[ApplicationThread]().InvokeAsynchronously(g(Application, libraryFolder, fileName, LibraryItemMetadataSettings(), DocumentSaveSettings()))
```

according to Tibco`s answer :

"Hopefully when Spotfire 7.5 is released we will have a more permanent solution to these types of issues since we can then select not to run the code inside a transaction from the UI."